# Exception: query() error.Login failed for user 'adminaa'

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, ado.net

In 20 years of microsoft programming I never have not been able to resolve this.

I have tried the normal stuff.

IIS 7.0, windows 7.0, SQL server 2012 all running locally, so there should be no trust or network issues.  been researching for a couple of hours and checking various stuff and I am not seeing any reason why this should not be working.

Here is what I have attempted for the normal stuff:

## 1

I used SA with it's user name password.  Got the same message.  went to SSMS and verified that the sa was a dbowner of the DB it is.  SSMS logged in as sa when connecting to SQL and verified that the password was correct through cutting and pasting from the web.config file into the text box.  I logged in no problem to SSMS and able to see the database

## 2

In SSMS I created a login adminaa user mapped it as db owner to the database.  I disconnected from sql server reconnected to it as this new user, no issues.  I plugged the new username and password in the config file.  Got the error can't login.  Went back to SSMS disconnected from sql server.  SSMS selected connect copied the username and password from the config file into the appropriate areas.  Connected to the sql server went and browsed to the database, I could see the data base ran a select query no problem.

I am at a loss.  Because the message is literally saying the log in is failing and nothing else when attempting to run a query.

This is the first time I have used this computer to do a asp.net to sql.

Comment: Are you sure that the connection string in your web.config is really used? Perhaps you connect with Integrated Security and the Application Pool Account is used?

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: How do you have the Web Application setup in IIS?  Which worker process identity are you using?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the questions.  I figured it out.  I don't know how but I have multiple instances for SQL Server on my machine.  Same version with slight variation.  It is attempting to log into the other instance and can't.  It is really really bizarre.  One is 11.0.2100 and the other is 11.0.2318.  Two different versions for SQL 2012 Express.  With 3 different sql servers showing in the connect dropdown list for the machine but even weirder is 2 of those selections are pointing to the same instance and one is pointing to a different version instance.  Really don't know how this happened.

Comment: Even weirder I can't connect the one sql server instance I want.  I go into properties use the name it has for my connection string and then get a error back saying it can't find the instance.  Checked to make sure TCP/IP is enabled on the server instance in the configuration area and it is.  Guess I am going to have to try and uninstall everything and try to clean up this machine.  But I don't know what I did to get multiple instances on this machine.